# How to read form data values shown on network tab of developer tools in controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

Trying to read form data[Developer tools: Network -> Payload -> FormData], below is the flow of code and how I tried to read and failed. Kindly help me in reading form data values - bearer & status. End goal is to read the bearer token which is actually added to the form by the returnee application and decode and use the data. Apologies if am asking a silly question or made mistakes somewhere in my question.

cshtml:

```
<form asp-action="TestAction" asp-controller="Account" method="GET" id="sign_in_form" novalidate="novalidate">
  <div id="signin">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Sign in" id="submit">
      </div>
  </div>
  @Html.Hidden("ReturnUrl", ViewData["ReturnUrl"] ?? string.Empty, new { id = "returnURLID" })
</form>
```

TestActionController:

```
[HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> TestAction()
    {
        return RedirectToLocal("https:someUrl.com/blah");
    }
```

After redirecting to 'https:someUrl.com/blah', I fill up few details and submit, then I`ll be redirected back to 'https://testlogin.com/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=/?state=State123'.

Code where control comes back and the code I tried:

```
[HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Login(string ReturnUrl = null)
    {

      if (HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
      {
        return RedirectToLocal(ReturnUrl);
      }
      else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ReturnUrl) && ReturnUrl.Contains("state=State123"))
      {

        //try 1
        try
        {
          var dict = Request.Form.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value.ToString());
          foreach (string key in HttpContext.Request.Form.Keys)
          {
            _errorService.InsertInformation($"dict[key]:{dict[key]}", "", 0, $"Login", Environment.MachineName);
          }
        }
        catch(Exception ee) { _errorService.InsertInformation($"ee:{ee}", "", 0, $"Login", Environment.MachineName); }

        //try 2
        try
        {
          Request.Body.Position = 0;
          var _body = new StreamReader(Request.Body).ReadToEnd();
          //read _body - which is empty. 
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
        }

        //try 3
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(
            Request.Body,
            encoding: Encoding.UTF8,
            detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks: false))
        {
          var bodyString = reader.ReadToEnd();
          //bodyString is empty 
          try
          {
          foreach (var _key in Request.Form.Keys)
          {
          }
          }catch{//It comes to catch block because Form is null}
        }
        
        return View();
      }
      else
      {
        // Some logic for session handling and others is done here.
        return View();
      }
    }
```

Developer tool screenshot:
[image: Developer tool showing form data]

Comment: Get Request do not have a body. I am not sure what you want to achieve but the bearer token is in the Authorization Header of your Request https://developer-mozilla-org.translate.goog/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization?_x_tr_sl=en&_x_tr_tl=de&_x_tr_hl=de&_x_tr_pto=sc

The next thing is that - besides of a hidden field - your form is empty. And the status is not in the body of the request. https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cics-ts/5.3?topic=protocol-http-requests

Comment: @SirOneOfMany - Token is added to the form data when the page is returned back from 'https://testlogin.com/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=/?state=State123'. Its a different application who adds jwt encoded token. Requirement is to decode and use the details required. Also about form, was just playing around with that to read data. Kindly suggest a fix.

Comment: Pal you blanked out everything in the last picture, are we supposed to guess what your form does? If we are talking about a Bearer JWT token then it is definetly not in the body but in the Authorization Header Field of your request. And GET request DO NOT have a body.
I really think you are mixing up things

Comment: @SirOneOfMany - Am not sure if am making things complicate here. But am just supposed to read the form data bearer highlighted in the screenshot. Its something getting added when returned back to the page by the other application where we are redirecting. If you think its not making sense, I`ll just hide or delete the post.

Comment: The thing is there is a lot of information missing in your post and there is no [minimal, reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). All I can say is that a GET Request does not have a body and a bearer token is in the authorization header field. And a redirect does not provide form data, just query paramters. And the last thing is how can you see the redirected stuff in your devtools?